# Why do spaces in regular expressions relative to '+' cause issues?

Tags: python, regex

In the Python code, I used `re.compile()` to to check whether given word is exists.

```
PATTERNS = {
    re.compile(r'[\w\s] + total+ [\w\s] + cases'): data.get_total_cases,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s] + total cases'): data.get_total_cases,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s] + total + [\w\s] + deaths'): data.get_total_deaths,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s] + total deaths'): data.get_total_deaths
}
```

This did not work as expected. I couldn't find anything wrong. Finally, I removed spaces after every character set `[\w\s]` because it was the only visible difference between my code and original code that I had referenced.

```
PATTERNS = {
    re.compile(r'[\w\s]+ total+ [\w\s]+ cases'): data.get_total_cases,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s]+ total cases'): data.get_total_cases,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s]+ total+ [\w\s]+ deaths'): data.get_total_deaths,
    re.compile(r'[\w\s]+ total deaths'): data.get_total_deaths
}
```

Now the code is working and all patterns can be successfully identified. But still I couldn't find why these spaces cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` symbol in a regex expression means "one or more of".

So  `+` means "one or more of  (space). And `[\w\s]+` means "one or more of any alphanumeric or whitespace characters".

If you are wanting to match a pattern that is like `10 total + 10 cases` with a `+` as a literal, you need to escape the `+` sign. a raw string (`r` before the string) allows for literal backslashes in the string, which can be used to escape in the regex pattern.

```
re.compile(r"[\w\s]+ total \+ [\w\s]+ cases")
```

Notice the `\+` which means "literally a + sign" rather than "one or more of".